# How to fetch data from api in React by using axois?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, axios

How to fetch only "33.3" that is inside data by using axios in React?

[image: da]

```
state = {
   oil: "",
};

async componentDidMount() {
   const link = "http://api.net/api/live?access_" //it is fake api
   const requiest = await axios.get(link);

   this.setState({
   oil: requiest.series.data[0],
});
console.log(this.state.oil);
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are facing? From the image, it seems like `series` is an array, so you might want to reconsider `requiest.series.data`

Comment: It says "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Comment: Can you try something like `requiest.series[0].data[0]`? How many objects are in your `series` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In axios the data object is inside response.data

So you should do:

```
state = {
   oil: "",
};

async componentDidMount() {
   const link = "http://api.net/api/live?access_" //it is fake api
   const requiest = await axios.get(link);

   this.setState({
   oil: requiest.data.series[0].data[0],
});
console.log(this.state.oil);
}
```

This will get you the first data of the first series array